# How to prefill the username/password fields on the login page

Tags: login

For a demo environment, I would like to pre-fill the username and password fields of the wp-login form with respectively "demo" and "demo" string.

Thus users will just need to click on the "Log-in" button to connect to the admin area.

There is a way to do that ? Maybe with a hook ?

Thanks for your advises

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Result

[image]

#### Username

You can declare the form field value global and prefill it.

> This will override any setting done via the "Remember me"-Checkbox.

```
/**
 * Changes the default user name to "DEMO"
 * 
 * @return string $user_login
 */
function login_form_username()
{
    global $user_login;
    return $user_login = 'DEMO';
}
add_action( 'login_head', 'login_form_username' );
```

#### Password

I found nothing that you can use to prefill it, so I'd add a note. Gladly/Sadly there's the whole set of stylesheets for the admin UI available. So `.wrap` in connection with `h2` gives a nice styling. The function is hooked to the additional fields hook for the admin hook. The priority is `0` to set it above additional fields.

```
/**
 * Adds a note beyond the user login name & password field
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function login_form_note()
{
    print '<div class="wrap"><h2 style="text-align: center;">The Password is "DEMO"</h2></div>';
}
add_action( 'login_form', 'login_form_note', 0 );
```

### Security: Hide Errors

As someone would get a visual proof that he entered an existing user name by default, I'd add the following to your functions.php file, to avoid telling if the username was guessed right:

```
/**
 * Hide wrong login names
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function no_login_error() 
{
    return __( 'Wrong Credentials.' );
}
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'no_login_error' );
```

### Other filters

*Notes:*

- If you want to replace other stuff like styles, then you can use the [`login_enqueue_scripts`](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) hook.
- You can also replace the link behind the logo using the `login_headerurl` filter that filters the url. The link `title` can be replaced using `login_headertitle`. Both trigger for multisite as well a single site setups.
- The login message can be changed using the `login_message` filter.

Answer (score 6):

you could use this code to auto login the user:

```
add_action('init', 'auto_login');
add_action('admin_init', 'auto_login');
function auto_login() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
      //by user name
      $user = get_user_by( 'login', 'demo' );
      //Or by user id, 2 being the ID of the demo user
      //$user = get_userdata(2);
      wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
      wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
      do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be even cooler if you wouldn't take the ID, but instead get the user by name. +1 anyway.

Comment: You can!  `get_user_by( 'login', 'demo' );`

Comment: Wouldn't the `init` hook be enough? It is present everywhere...

Answer (score 3):

Here are 3 ways to do it:

The first way is to use the [wp_signon hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

```
$creds = array();    
$creds['user_login'] = 'example';   
$creds['user_password'] = 'plaintextpw';   
$creds['remember'] = true;   
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );  
if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {  
   echo $user->get_error_message();
}
```

The second way, is to use jQuery `.val()` and add it to your login page

```
$("#user_login").val('username');    
$("#user_pass").val('password');
```

The last way is to edit your `wp-login.php` file (Note, this is not recommended although it would work).

Comment: 1) would need a replacement for the whole wp-login.php file - How would you do that (serious Q - I'm interested)? Rewrite rules so your template would get triggered instead? 2) is valid, but would need jQuery and be wrapped into a `jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ )` call to make `$` available and the function working. You'd also need to call `jQuery` only for this. 3) Ok, well... Let's just say nothing about it :)

Comment: 1) I'm not sure, I was mostly brain storming never done it. as for 2) it looks like jquery is already loaded in my login page. I was also being lazy and not wrapping my example in `jQuery(document...` tags. 3) It never happened.