# Passing username to login screen

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I would like to user a single field form to pass a username to the wp-login (without password)

something like `mysite.com/wordpress/wp-login?username=dave` - although the form could, of course be POST rather than GET

I can find lots of advice on how **not** to pass the password, sensibly enough, but passing the username isn't particularly dangerous as these wouldn't be admin users.

Answer (score 1):

This code should accomplish what you're after:

```
function login_username() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
        echo "    <style type='text/css'>               
        body.login #user_login, body.login label[for=user_login] {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>\n";
        global $user_login;
        return $user_login = sanitize_user($_REQUEST['username'], true);
    }
}
add_action('login_head', 'login_username');
```

Since you're on the login page, `get_query_var()` isn't an option, but you can retrieve and pass the username with a sanitized `$_REQUEST['username']`.

Adding the CSS will hide the username field (I'm assuming that's what you were asking for) when the username has been passed via the url.

Comment: Looks like it should do it. Thank you. I don't need to hide the username but the swapping the REQUEST variable into the $user_login variable is exactly what I need. Amazingly enough this conversation seemed to trigger a related post with the answer ( I did search, honest!) so this might be a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39994/how-to-prefill-the-username-password-fields-on-the-login-page